# How to create unique locator of this tag in selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

How to create unique locator of this tag.
once it created but tag value contain some character and it's throwing syntax error.
if i used on click attribute value.

```
Onclick="SetActiveDeative(this,'nash@imageworldllc.com');"
```

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: You can use \ to escape `'` or `"` character...

Answer (score 0):

Locate an input box which name is username

```
<input id="login-user" data-localize="core.login.user" name="username"/>

xpath locator:
//input[@name='username']
```

Locate an form which style is "display: block;" and **onsubmit** function is "return false"

```
<form id="login-form" onsubmit="return false" style="display: block;">

xpath locator:
//form[@style="display: block;"][@onsubmit="return false"]
```

Locate an link which Onclick function is SetActiveDeative(this,'nash@imageworldllc.com');

```
//a[@Onclick="SetActiveDeative(this,'nash@imageworldllc.com');"]
```

[image: XPATH is validated via Firebug and is working]

Comment: I used but when i use this in the my java code then its throw syntax error.

Comment: @nikhilchoudhary please give us more details including your java code snippets and the error message.

Comment: My xpath :- //a[contains(@onclick,"SetActiveDeative(this,'guerriero.megan@dol.gov');")]

Comment: My java code :- test.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@onclick,"SetActiveDeative(this,'guerriero.megan@dol.gov');")]")).click();

Comment: So if i used above xpath in java code to find element then its trowing syntax error.

Comment: @nikhilchoudhary you should escape the double quotes. The argument passed to By.xpath("//a[contains(@onclick,\"SetActiveDeative(this,'guerriero.megan@dol.gov');\")]") .

Comment: Thanks but its not working. Because by using this xpath unable to find element in the Mozilla browser.

Comment: Please share code if u have. If user get multiple matching nodes and to choose from one of them and click on that.

Comment: @nikhilchoudhary what's the element source code? Without sharing the details, it's hard to figure out the issue.

Comment: Have you ever tested the xpath locator via Firebug? I created an html and tested via Firebug. The xpath in my anwser is working. https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5Kjl.png.

Comment: Ok you give me a firepath its working and showing one matching node. Now you just put this fire path in the java code then its trowing syntax error.

Comment: Did you escape the double quotes?

Comment: Java code:-      test.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@onclick="SetActiveDeative(this,'nash@imageworldllc.com');"]")).click();